# Recordar option de un select al volver a pag principal

Tags: php, html

En una página principal tengo un select con varios option, al elegir uno y pulsar un botón Aceptar voy a otra página que muestra el option seleccionado, y al volver quiero que se cargue la página principal con el mismo option

Este es el código de la página principal

```html
<html>


<?

 if(isset($_POST[val]))
 {
  echo "<form action=pag2.php method=post><select name=casillas>";
  if($_POST[val]=="Casilla1")
   echo "<option value=Casilla1 selected>Casilla 1</option>";
  else echo "<option value=Casilla1>Casilla 1</option>";
  if($_POST[val]=="Casilla2")
   echo "<option value=Casilla2 selected>Casilla 2</option></select>";
  else echo "<option value=Casilla2>Casilla 2</option></select>";
  echo " <input type=submit value=Aceptar name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
  echo "</form>";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "<form action=pag2.php method=post><select name=casillas>";
   echo "<option value=Casilla1>Casilla 1</option>";
   echo "<option value=Casilla2>Casilla 2</option></select>";
  echo " <input type=submit value=Aceptar name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
  echo "</form>";
 }

?>


</html>
```

Este sería el código de la segunda página

```html
<html>

<?

 echo "<form action=ppal.php method=post>";
 if(isset($_POST[casillas]))
 {
  if ($_POST[casillas]=="Casilla1") echo "Casilla 1 elegida";
  else echo "Casilla 2 elegida";
 }
 else echo "No, así no vale";

 echo "<br><input type=submit value=Volver name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
 echo "<input type=hidden name=val value=" . $_POST[casillas] . ">";
 echo "</form>";

?>


</html>
```

Son dos páginas php, la principal y la segunda. Funciona correctamente tal como lo tengo, pero quiero poner un enlace en lugar de botones, tanto para ir a la segunda página, como para volver a la principal

Se podría hacer?

Gracias!

Comment: tanto `casillas` como `val` que están dentro de los `$_POST` son variables o strings? Tienen que ser forzosamente formularios POST? no podrían ser GET

Comment: Podrias utiliar $_SESSION[ ] este coloca la variable en cache y no se ira hasta cerrar el navegador o recargar la pagina forzando borrar cache, para resolver tu pregunta podrias poner una condicion sobre la session para que ejecute el codigo si la session tiene algo diferente a null. espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Y así condicionar tu código a que si regresas la variable que esta en cache llene el input que quieres que se mantenga.

Comment: Y cómo paso los options con session??? Primero inicio la sesión con session_start() y luego tengo que crear variables de sesión para los options?

Answer (score 0):

Hola le realice algunos ajustes a tu código:

**ppal.php:**

```
<html>
<?php
    //Los atributos del POST van entre comillas
    if(isset($_POST['val']))
    {
        echo "<form action=pag2.php method=post><select name=casillas>";
        //Si eligio Casilla 1 se selecciona su valor y el otro no
        if($_POST['val']=="Casilla1"){
            echo "<option value=Casilla1 selected>Casilla 1</option>";
            echo "<option value=Casilla2>Casilla 2</option></select>";
        //Si eligio Casilla 2 se selecciona su valor y el otro no
        } else if($_POST['val']=="Casilla2"){
            echo "<option value=Casilla1>Casilla 1</option>";   
            echo "<option value=Casilla2 selected>Casilla 2</option></select>";
        }
        echo " <input type=submit value=Aceptar name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
        echo "</form>";
    } else {
        echo "<form action=pag2.php method=post><select name=casillas>";
            echo "<option value=Casilla1>Casilla 1</option>";
            echo "<option value=Casilla2>Casilla 2</option></select>";
        echo " <input type=submit value=Aceptar name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
        echo "</form>";
    }

?>
</html>
```

**pag2.php:**

```
<html>

<?php

    echo "<form action=ppal.php method=post>";
    //Los atributos del POST van entre comillas
    if(isset($_POST['casillas'])){
        if ($_POST['casillas']=="Casilla1") echo "Casilla 1 elegida";
        else echo "Casilla 2 elegida";
    } else{
        echo "No, así no vale";
    }

    echo "<br><input type=submit value=Volver name=Aceptar id=Aceptar>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=val value=" . $_POST['casillas'] . ">";
    echo "</form>";
?>
</html>
```